Image of a point under a restriction of Cremona transformation
I’m working on the Section 2.3, Exercise 6 of Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, by Igor Shafarevich:
Exercise 6. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^2\to\mathbb{P}^2$ be the rational map defined by $\varphi(x_0:x_1:x_2)=(x_1x_2:x_0x_2:x_0x_1)$. Consider the point $x=(1:0:0)$ and the curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ that is nonsingular at $x$. By Theorem 2.12 (Which asserts that a rational map of a nonsingular curve to projective space is regular), the map $\varphi$ restricted to $C$ is regular at $x$, and therefore maps $x$ to some point that we denote $\varphi_C(x)$. Prove that $\varphi_{C_1}(x)=\varphi_{C_2}(x)$ if and only if $\Theta_{C_1,x}=\Theta_{C_2,x}$, where $\Theta_{C,x}$ is the tangent space to $C$ at $x$.
This is what I've tried: I thought it is enough to show that, for any curve $C\ni x$ such that $x$ is nonsingular, $\varphi_{C}(x)=\varphi_{\Theta_{C,x}}(x)$. Suppose that $C=V(F)$ for some homogenous $F\in k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$. The tangent space $\Theta_{C,x}$ is given by the equation $\sum_{i=0}^2\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x)x_i$. Write $a_i=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x)$. Since $x$ is on the tangent line, $a_0=0$. So the equation for the tangent line is $a_1x_1+a_2x_2=0$. Say that $a_2\neq 0$. Then the restriction $\varphi|_{\Theta_{C,x}}(x)$ is given by $(x_0:x_1:x_2)\mapsto(-a_1x_1:-a_1x_0:a_2x_2)$. So $\varphi_{\Theta_{C,x}}(x)=(0:-a_1,a_2)=(0:-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x):\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}(x))$. Now I'm trying to find a tuple $\varphi|_C=(G_0:G_1:G_2)$ of forms $G_i$ of same degree that is equal to $\varphi$ on $C$ and that $(G_0(x):G_1(x):G_2(x))=(0:-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}(x):\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}(x))$, but I couldn't find.
Can you please give me a hint to solve this problem? Thank you for your help in advance.

I think you can consider the blow-up at $x$. $\varphi$ can be extended on the preimage of $x$ under the blow-up. The each point in the preimage of $x$ represents a tangent at $x$。

Moreover, $\tilde{\varphi}(y)$ varies from $y$ for any $y$ in the preimage of $x$ under the blow up/
